# Azure Devops Extensions - Receive Service Hooks?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

Is it possible for an azure devops extension to receive web hooks and take actions while the user is not currently using azure devops e.g. when a pr is updated because the build finished, can an extension be notified?

I am trying to understand if I need an external api as well or if the azure devops extensions can take care of both interactive and non interactive tasks (still on behalf of a user).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, it is not possible. Az Extension is running in browser's iFrame and is completely isolated from web server.

I have built C# WebServer that receives service hook messages and this works fine. But this is external API.